# Add navigation inside canDeactivate method

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

CanDeactivate Guards.

Is it possible that when leaving a component, the canDeactivate not only renders a confirmation window with yes/no, but also navigates to another component?
Something like this:

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
if (this.registrationService.isRegistered()) {
  return true;
} else {
  if (!confirm('If you do not register, your data will be lost. Click Cancel to go to Registration page.')) {
    console.log('before');
    this.router.navigate(['register']); // <----
    console.log('after');
    return false;
  } else { return true; }
}
```

}

Now it's not work. When click Cancel just again and again open confirmation window and in cosole is: 'before', 'after'. Redirect to registration page only if first click to Cancel and than to Ok.

UPDATE:
It`s seems i solved these with PROMISE

```
private isCanDeactivate: boolean;
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
 if (this.registrationService.isRegistered()) {
   return true;
 } else {
   if (!confirm('If you do not register, your data will be lost. Click Cancel to go to Registration page.')) {
     console.log('press Cancel');
     this.retrieve().then(() => this.afterPromise());
     return this.isCanDeactivate;
   } else {
     console.log('press Ok');
     return true; }
  }
}

private retrieve(): Promise<any> {
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
   this.retrieveDataResolver = resolve;
   this.setIsCanDeactivate();
 });
}

private setIsCanDeactivate(): void {
 this.isCanDeactivate = true;
 this.retrieveDataResolver();
}
private afterPromise() {
 this.router.navigate(['register']);
}
```

Can someone help with a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the **register** component path is 'register' you can do it in the following way

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('register');
```

Also You can use `location.back()` for navigation to the last page.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
 })
class LoginPage {

  constructor(private location: Location) 
  {}

  onBackClicked() {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but in canDeactivate() method of canDeactevate guars it`s not work. I add console.log in code above: wirte 'before', 'after', but not navigated (with router.navigate or router.navigateByUrl)

Comment: `const routes: Routes = [ ... 

  {
    path: 'match',
    component: MatchValueCompatibilityComponent,
    canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
  }...

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }`